# Import primsa schema into graphql schema

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo-server, prisma

Im updating a project from graphql-yoga to apollo-server. I load a primsa schema into my graphql schema (schema.graphql) using this line `# import * from './generated/prisma.graphql'` , under graphql-yoga this then imported the prisma types into the schema.

However as it is yoga doing this, when upgrading from yoga, this simply does not happen. I managed to get this to work using graphql-import (assume it imports the schema), however as its deprecated I am unable to use this as a solution.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this using graphql-tools please? Below is how I create my apollo-server instance.

```
const sources = loadTypedefsSync(__dirname + '/schema.graphql', { loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()] })

const typeDefs = sources.map(source => source.document)

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, ...resolvers })
const schemaWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(schema, permissions)

const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema: schemaWithMiddleware,
    context: ({ req }) => ({
      ...req,
      db
    }),

  })
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

It is recommend by the maintainers of GraphQL Import to migrate to GraphQL Tools. There is a straight forward migration from GraphQL Import example provided by GraphQL Tools in the docs.

[Migration from GraphQL Import](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/migration-from-import/)